# Regular expression for number in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I want a regular expression for only numbers, not less 3 and more than 7 digit and also it should not accept characters.

I tried `(/^[0-9]{3,7}$/)` - this but it is accepting some character like 'e'. eg: 1e3, 23e4, 123e4 are failing.

Comment: post some valid in valid inputs and expected output with ur attempts

Comment: Show code how `/^[0-9]{3,7}$/` is failing for you?

Comment: Why do you need a regexp for this? Just do `!isNan(val) && +val >= 100 && +val < 100000000`. By the way, no-one here cares if it is urgent.

Comment: Please write the question more clearly. "but it is accepting some character like 'e'. eg: 1e3, 23e4, 123e4 are failing". Is it accepting, or failing? Or did you mean "excepting"?

Comment: @anubhava: yeah, I tried this also but didn't work.

Comment: @torazaburo:It is accepting e.

Comment: @anubhava: 
((/^[0-9]{3,7}$/.test(1e3)))

Comment: `1e3` is actually 1000. You need to test: `/^[0-9]{3,7}$/.test('1e3')` and that will return false.

Comment: what is the difference between /^[0-9]{3,7}$/.test(+1e3) and /^[0-9]{3,7}$/.test(1e3)

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that `1e3` is a *number* written in [engineering notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E_notation), not a *string*. The `e` means "times 10 to the power of", so `1e3` means 1 x 10^3 = 1000, and `23e4` means 230000. If this is the case, when you convert the number `1e3` to a string, the output will be "1000", which represents a number with not less than 3 digits and not more than 7, so it is right that your regex matches this.

Comment: Umm, he is saying that his regexp does **not** match numbers written in scientific notation.

Comment: My guess is that the OP is saying "it is accepting... 'e'. [numbers which are displayed with an 'e'] are failing [to be rejected]." Let's wait and see how s/he responds.

Comment: @JamesNewton: You are right, all these are numbers which falls between 3-7 character length.
I have to put this check on text field which should accept number only. So how to differentiate whether 1e3 is a number or string?

Comment: In JavaScript, you can use `typeof`. See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lexogram/1r2v3n2b/1/)